# i have faced problem with django runserver command on cmd

Tags: python, django

hi guys i have facing problem with python

> python manage.py runserver

it doesn't work on command line it opening the python IDLE

Comment: Does it print any error? You should provide more information, since your problem might be too broad.

Comment: no man no errors or anything  just after i press enter the IDLE window opens for second and get closed and in cmd just ignore the command and start a  new one

Comment: as salam mu alaikum, brother did you install django globally or locally?? it happens if you install it locally

Comment: Can you tell me the difference and how do i install django globally